# why is my sculpt brush is destroying the mesh

Tags: sculpting

when i use the sculpt brush to smooth the adges on my characters arm it makes it really bumpy[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file, at least the part that you're trying to sculpt: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Maybe do a remesh first so you get a nice quad mesh? The upper arm looks like it was created by extrusion. At the side, there might be not enough vertices and faces could be flipped. Try Shift+R to set the voxel size and then Ctrl+R to remesh.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.